# Como limitar numero de chamada do banco de dados em monitores diferentes

Tags: php

Bom meu problema é o seguinte, meu site é configurado pra android e desktop, ai chamo os dados pelo banco de dados e uso o `LIMIT` ai ele mostra tanto "x", eu gostaria de saber como usar o `LIMIT` pra desktop valor "x" e pra android outro valor, alguém saberia como eu poderia fazer ? aqui está um pedaço do meu código

```
<?php
  $strSQL = sprintf("SELECT * FROM `livros` WHERE limita = 'inicio' AND status = 'velho_testamento' LIMIT");
  $stmt = $mysql->execute($strSQL);
  while($row = $stmt->fetchObject()){
     echo '<li><a href="capitulos.php?id_livro='.$row->id_livro.'" class="'.$row->responsive.'">'.$row->nome_livro.'</a></li>';
  }
?>
```

Comment: a principio você teria que pegar o `user-agent` pelo front end, e enviar como parametro para o back-end, assim voce conseguiria saber e tratar os dados.

Comment: poderia dar um exemplo? sou iniciante

Answer (score 0):

Com `PHP` é complicado mas tem um jeito.

```
<?php if(!isset($_GET['mobile'])) {?>
    <script>

    if(window.innerWidth < 920){
         window.location.href = "?mobile=true";
    }
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

O php verifica se `$_GET['mobile']` existe caso não exista, ele imprime um código javascript capaz de capturar a largura, caso seja `< X`, redireciona para a mesma página passando a global `mobile`, ai é só verificar

```
<?php

$limit = (isset($_GET['mobile'])) ? 10 : 30;

...
?>
```

De forma alguma recomendo fazer isso.